# How can I save missions to play later in GTA 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Can I skip missions and play them later? For example, I want to play The Big Score first and then Lester's assassination later.

Comment: Pretty sure there is a replay mission option somewhere in the menu.

Comment: @TimmyJim you *can* replay missions, but some (like the Lester assassination ones) will only affect the stock market the first time around, so you don't want to do them until you've completed the final mission and have the maximum amount of cash on each character to multiply.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the assassination missions until after the final heist, you can. With one exception; the first one "The Hotel Assassination" is required to advance the main story. So before you go to Lester for that one, ensure you've done all the collectibles that award money. And then after the hotel assassination, you just don't go to the green "L" on your map as Franklin until after the final heist has paid out.

([Be sure to prepare appropriately before each assassination for maximum payout](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Assassination_Investor))